# No more support for firebase triggers?

Tags: firebase, zapier

I just got an E-mail from zapier (https://zapier.com/), that stated, that the firebase triggers are no longer supported! What is up with that? My production system was using the triggers to integrate 3rd party tools!

Regards,
Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is due to changes to Firebase after Google purchased them. That is why Zapier has added a keystore application to try to replace it.